# How to recompile an x64 blender python script for x86 computers?

Tags: python, x86, blender, bpy

I'm trying to get a blender addon, animation nodes, working on a x86 computer. To my lack of luck, there's only 64 bit builds avalible.

In the past, I've found a previously compiled version of the addon - unluckily, this was for blender 2.78, and not 2.8.

https://blender.community/5d28871ad3ac8b41e5d7215c/download/5d288762d3ac8b41e5d7215e is the code.

Upon importing the addon into 2.8, I get the standard Could not compile wall of text. When importing the older addon, it comes up as upgrade to 2.8x required, as usual.

Comment: For now it's not supported and likely won't be in the future since 32 bit systems are getting fewer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119253/where-i-can-find-latest-compiled-animation-nodes-for-windows-7-32-bit

Answer (score 0):

If the supplied addon distributions don't work for you, then you need to [compile your own version](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev_guide/setup/windows.html).

You will need [cython](https://cython.org/) and a C/C++ compiler to compile the addon. Your python version should match the blender install which is v3.7 for blender 2.80

- Download the [git repo](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) and checkout the blender2.8 branch
- Create `conf.json` at the top of the repo and set the `Copy Target` to the location of your blender addons directory
- Run `python setup.py build --copy` to build and install animation nodes
- Alternatively use `python setup.py build --export` to build it into a zip file for you to install manually